# How do I create an object with empty values?

Tags: javascript, json

If I want to create a callback object, like so:

```
var callback = {
    err:'String',
    data:'String'
};
```

How can I create this object without initializing `err` and `data` with values? Can I?

I need to check if err is undefined, so I can know if I need to handle errors or not, since this is a callback.

Comment: why do you want no values as opposed to just an empty string? `''` you  have to use something. it could be an empty string, true/false, undefined, etc.

Comment: Why initialize them ahead of time? Unless you're using `strict`, they'll be initialized when you assign to them the first time.

Comment: `var back = {};`. Unknown properties will be `undefined` by default: `console.log(back.err); // undefined`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Set that as an answer and I'll accept it. Or if Zdravko  expands on his answer to include that information (it's only implied), I'll accept that

Comment: if (typeof(back.err) !== 'undefined') // you gots yo'self an error

Comment: @tenub If I send it an empty string of `''`, will that if statement return true?

Comment: @Houseman If by "*it*" you mean `back.err`, then yes it'll pass as `true` as the `typeof ''` is not `'undefined'`.

Comment: @tenub So that's why I want no values as opposed to an empty string, unless I misinterpreted your comments

Comment: when i made my original comment i thought you needed the `err` and `data` properties, therefore requiring values of some sort in order to be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an empty object like this:

```
var o = { };
```

Comment: and then simply set properties like `o.err = 1234;`

Comment: If I do this, `err` and `data` will be undefined when I try to look for them. I can later assign either of those if I need to. I just wanted to explicitly explain this.

Answer (score 1):

The "no value" thing is called "undefined" in javascript, so you have to set their values to undefined.

```
obj = Object.create({}, {
    err:  { writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true },
    data: { writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
})
```

or even simpler:

```
var undef;

obj = {
    err:  undef,
    data: undef
}
```

In response to your edit, it would be easier to create an empty object initially, and then check if `err` is defined by using `in`:

```
 if('err' in obj)
     got an error!
```

Comment: Instead of using if('err' in obj), use obj.hasOwnProperty('err'). This will avoid searching too deep down the prototype chain

Answer (score 1):

```
var callback = {};
```

When looking for `err` or `data` the values will be undefined. You can assign them to whatever you'd like later.